# Python/wxPython: AUI Manager, Prevent Panel from Leaving the Frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using the code below to test some of the features from AUI.  If you run the code, you should find a frame with 2 panels in it that can be detached/floated.  However, the panel can be dragged anywhere on the screen.  I'd like to prevent the panel from leaving the main frame.  Is this possible?  I thought there would be a flag or something that I can change, but I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Thanks!

Code:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw import aui

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keys):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
        self.textCtrl = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, 'AGW is a very nice library!' )

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keys):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
        self.mgr = mgr = aui.AuiManager_DCP()
        mgr.SetManagedWindow( self )
        mgr.AddPane( TestPanel(self), aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name('p1').Caption('p1').Right().BestSize((100,100)) )
        mgr.AddPane( TestPanel(self), aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name('p2').Caption('p2').Bottom().BestSize((100,100)) )
        mgr.Update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App( redirect = False )
    frame = TestFrame( None, title = 'AUI test', size = (300, 400) )
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AuiPaneInfo()` you can add `Floatable(False)` to the pane you dont want it to float:

```
wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().Left().Floatable(False)
```

Comment: Actually, I do want the pane to float.  I want it to be floating, to be able to be resized, maximized, closed, etc.  But I just want it to stay within the frame, even when floating.  Is this not (easily) possible?

Comment: I guess what you need is MDI window (the window inside the window) then. You can download the wxPython demo http://www.wxpython.org/download.php. There are a lot of examples and demo codes.

Comment: Ya, looks like you're right (MDI is what I'd need).  I think I'll try re-thinking my layout instead..